# issue displaying multiple users info by id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get it where it will get the friends id from the friends table, and then get the friends information from the users table. I've tried using a foreach but had no luck.

Here's what I have right now where it's only echoing one friend and not the three that I have in the table. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Maybe I wasn't using the for each properly? Thank You In Advance!

```
<?php 
//Gets users information from users. 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT  friendsid FROM friends WHERE userid='.$_SESSION['user']['id']);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    extract($row);
}   else {
    $friendsid = $row['friendsid'];
} 

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT username,userprofile,status FROM users WHERE id='.$friendsid);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
        extract($row);
        ?>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h4><strong><?php echo $row['username'];?></strong></h4>
                        <img src="images/profile/<?php echo $userprofile;?>" class="img-circle" height="70" width="70" alt="Avatar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3 class="text-left"><?php echo $row['status'];?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php
    }
} else {
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That is not how prepared statements should be used. Parameterize.

Comment: I'd get rid of lines 4-20 and get all the data with 1 query. Use a `join`. Don't use `extract`.

Comment: @chris85  So it should be like this? 
`SELECT users.id, users.username, users.userprofile
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends
ON users.id=friends.friendsid;`

Comment: Something like that, yea. Not sure of your data structure. You'll need a `where` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements use parameters and you should use a JOIN.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT u.* FROM users AS u JOIN friends AS f ON u.id = f.friendsid WHERE f.userid = :user_id');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // Do whatever you want with $row['id'], $row['username'], $row['userprofile']
}
```

Comment: Would I extract the row still? to display all of the users friends?

Comment: @BigfellaHQ No, don't extract. Almost never extract. `$row` will have your data.

Comment: No need to extract. You can use $row array directly.

Comment: Ahh, So i can just call it now, like `$row['username'];` ? and it will display all of the friends usernames?

Comment: Yes, the loop will display a username each time with $row['username']

Comment: Ok. Is there a good place to learn how joins work? Because I was on W3schools and they didn't have very much information

Comment: Sweet! Thank You!